# Upon receiving treatment, John's condition recuperated

Tags: grammar

"Upon receiving treatment, John's condition recuperated."

Is the word "recuperated" correctly used in this sentence?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not correct. John himself *recuperated*, but his condition *improved*.

Comment: It would sound unfortunate for John if his *condition* recuperated. Assuming, of course, he wasn't particularly fond of said condition. +1 ... but is the construction actually ungrammatical?

Comment: *Condition* lies outside the universe of things that can recuperate, that is, living things and entities under their agency. A corporation, sports team, a house can *recuperate*. So can a pond if the beavers are busy.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is John that recuperated, not his condition.

[recuperate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/recuperate) :

> to recover from sickness or exhaustion; regain health or strength.

Comment: That isn't correct, as that definition suggests a doctor — or a week in the Bahamas — could *recuperate* you, when the word means "to *be* restored to health, etc."

Comment: According to the link, it can be used transitively. But I've edited the answer to reference the intransitive version the OP was asking about.

Comment: There is apparently a transitive American usage. In the same way one recuperates financial losses, one can recuperate one's health. There is no direct object in the OP's examples, so your edit was a good move.